# Global variable Scope

Tags: php

Its possible to use global variables declared in one function into an another function in php?

Comment: Of course, that's why they are called **global** variables.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
function func_A () {
    global $var;
    $var = 5;
}

function func_B () {
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}

func_A();
func_B();
```

echoes 5.

What happens when you use the `global` keyword is, PHP makes a note that the variable name you gave refers to that variable name in the global scope (whether or not that variable exists in the global scope at that time).

Use of global functions should be avoided where possible, as they can lead to functions having side-effects.

edit: I mean "global variables", not "global functions".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see [PHP Manual - Variable scope - The global keyword](http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope#language.variables.scope.global)